# HTML Signature in Evolution

Tags: evolution

I've tried cut and pasting the html code for my email signature that works fine in various other email clients and doing it in html formating, not text, when saving the signature, but the code never turns into the proper formatting.  Instead it just shows the text of the html code when I try to use the signature.

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a bug in Evolution 3.10.4

There is a simple workaround though. Write your html signature in a file called signature.html Test that it works by opening it in `Firefox`. Then when you have finished writing a message add the signature by using menu item `insert -> html file`.

Comment: This worked for me, but **before** using `insert -> html file`, I needed to change the `Format` dropdown value from `plaintext` to `HTML`.  If I changed the `Format` value **after** `insert`, then it would **not** work.

Comment: I know this thread is old, but am I expected to do it every single time I compose a new e-mail. This thread is still relevant as much as html signature do not work in the latest version of Evolution still (3.36.3)

Comment: To automatically insert your signature, go to Edit -> Preferences -> Mail Accounts -> Click on the Account Name -> Edit -> Identity. Under Optional Information, Pick the Signature and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

The better workaround is to create signature.html and signature.sh (also chmod +x it)
signature.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat ~/.signature.html
```

In Evolution: File -> Composer Preferences -> Signatures -> Add Script -> your script on file system

Answer (score 0):

`signature.sh` doesn't work for me.  I got this to work by:

1. Create `signature.html` file
2. Test in Firefox as above.
3. Insert into a new email message in Evolution.
4. Copy the inserted signature.
5. Paste the signature in an "Add Signature" dialog.
6. New signature can be inserted and looks as expected.

Now, I can't seem to get the signature to automatically be inserted into email messages....

Answer (score 0):

Seems still not to be fixed in Evolution...

Another workaround:

- Go to ~/.config/evolution/signatures
- Add a "dummy" html Signature in Evolution
- This will have create a new file in signatures folder (filename is random id)
- open this new file and paste your real html code there (without double dash+space)